# Using reference in Mongoose with ExpressJS

Tags: express, mongoose, reference

Since I've noticed that deep nesting arrays in documents is not good practice, I wanted to use `references` in Mongoose using ExpressJS. Now I am making a CMS where there are menu items which the user can post. Each menu item can have sub items that the user can also post. But I don't know how to use referencing so I can reference between the main items collection and the sub items collection.

This is my Main_items Mongoose model:

```
var menuItems = new mongoose.Schema({
  title : String,
  subitem: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'sub_items'
  }
}, {collection: 'menu_items'});

module.exports = mongoose.model("menu_items", menuItems);
```

And the sub_items model:

```
var subItems = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("sub_items", subItems);
```

Post of main_menu items

```
postController.postMainItems = function(req,res,item){
  var saveData = {
    title : req.body.title
  };
  var data = new item(saveData);
  saveToDB(data,res);
};
```

I already created a post for the main menu items. That works. But now I want to know how I can post the sub items so they are directly referenced to each main item

Comment: You need to create `menu` first and then `submenu` right ?

Comment: Yes, I want each menu item to have it's own subitems

Comment: Post code that you used to create `main menu items`

Comment: I have edited the code with the main_menu post

Answer (score 0):

Change the Schema as below, So that you need to insert the `main menu` first with `title` and then sub menu with `title` and `parent(_id of parent main menu)`.

**Main Menu Schema:**

```
var menuItems = new mongoose.Schema({
  title : String
}, {collection: 'menu_items'});

module.exports = mongoose.model("menu_items", menuItems);
```

**Sub Menu Schema:**

```
var subItems = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  parent: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'menu_items'}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("sub_items", subItems);
```